# Add linebreak in knitr sweave, keeping tidy=TRUE

Tags: r, knitr, sweave

I know I can format all my code manually if I set tidy=FALSE for the relevant code block, but I love the tidy=TRUE option.  It makes my code look good!  But I have a long vector that I want to print and it is going off the line and causing a LaTeX badbox.

Edit -- I know people like examples.  Here's an example.

```
<<HolySnail>>=
X <- data.frame(p1=c(0,2,0,0,-1,1),
                p2=c(3,0,1,1,0,1),
                p3=c(0,0,3,2,1,1))
poor_formatting_requires_tidying <- function(x,y,z) { a <- x*y+z; return(a+z) }
@
```

Edit -- the question is "How can I force knitr to respect the linebreaks in the definition of X without setting tidy=FALSE?"

Comment: You might want to add a question to your question

Comment: you can set tidy to false for one chunk and it will keep your formatting for x. since the other function is a single line, it wouldnt matter for that one anyway. And I always thought that tidy = TRUE made the code look like shit, but that is personal opinion. I mean, that is why you insert line breaks in code anyway--to make it more readable and aesthetically appealing, right?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess you were just looking for an option to control the width of your source code? Setting the width is very tricky with `tidy = TRUE`; you often have to try different values to get an appropriate width. You can use the `tidy.opts` option to pass the `width.cutoff` argument to `formatR::tidy.source()`, e.g.

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
<<HolySnail, tidy.opts=list(width.cutoff=60)>>=
X <- data.frame(p1=c(0,2,0,0,-1,1),
                p2=c(3,0,1,1,0,1),
                p3=c(0,0,3,2,1,1))
poor_formatting_requires_tidying <- function(x,y,z) { a <- x*y+z; return(a+z) }
@
\end{document}
```

Note `width.cutoff` only sets the minimal width, which means the output may well be wider than your setting. It depends on whether R can really break the code after `width.cutoff` characters.

After you struggle more with tweaking the width value, you probably will just go back to `tidy = FALSE`...

Comment: OK, I went to tidy=FALSE.  Thanks for your thoughtful response.